# Two events from different rows to be combined to one

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data from Mixpanel with two different events, with the same distinct_id. This data is then extracted into columns.

The data needs to be pivoted in SQL to display the output of the two events on the same row.

Data example:

```
| distinct_id | event | output_event1 | output_event2 |  
|-------------|-------|---------------|---------------|  
| 78          | event1| output1       | NULL          |  
| 78          | event2| NULL          | output2       |
```

Desired output:

```
| distinct_id | output_event1 | output_event2 |  
|-------------|---------------|---------------|  
| 78          | output1       | output2       |
```

The query I've tried so far tries two `with` clauses but that's inefficient, and I would like to have more information from the same table displayed in more columns. Another limitation of this version of the query is that it displays the ID not the event output for `event1` but that's fixable with a subquery... which I think would be further inefficient and am looking for help with.

```
with event1 as (
                select max(e.id) as id, e.event1, e.distinct_id -- multiple events are possible, select most recent one
                from mixpanel.events e where event='event1' 
                group by event, distinct_id)
, event2 as (
                select e.id, e.event, e.distinct_id, e.event2
                from mixpanel.events e where event='event2')
select s.distinct_id, s.id, f.id, f.event2 
from event1 s 
left join event2 f on s.distinct_id=f.distinct_id
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not remove the sub-queries and use the aggregate in your main query?

```
select
   distinct_id
   ,output_event1 = max(output_event1)
   ,output_event2 = max(output_event2)
from
   yourTable
group by
   distinct_id
```

Comment: This looks like the simplest way to go, +1

Comment: Thanks, I had to play around a bit with the columns that needed to have the grouping on them, but this works.

Answer (score 1):

If you have other event types in `event` and or can not use a simple `max()` for some reason;

using conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    distinct_id
  , output_event1 = max(case when event='event1' then event1 end)
  , output_event2 = max(case when event='event2' then event2 end)
from mixpanel.events
group by distinct_id
```

Comment: 1 from me since I don't think the question likely listed all the details :)